# Function continuity of defined functions at zero

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I am currently solving the following problems:

For each of the functions below decide (and briefly justify), whether it is contiguous at 0.

$$ f_1(x) = \begin{cases}
      x & \text{for } x \in \mathbb{Q}, \\
      -x & \text{for } x \notin \mathbb{Q}
   \end{cases}
$$

$$ f_2(x) = \begin{cases}
      0 & \text{for } x = 0, \\
      e^{\frac{-1}{x}} & \text{for } x \ne 0
   \end{cases}
$$

I am struggling with proving this once the function is defined in the following way. For the second one as we operate in $ \mathbb{R}$ numbers I would just investigate the leftside and rightside limits and whether they are equal and eventually whether it is  equal to zero. I would say that it's not.

For the first option here I would say that the one-side limits are equal to zero. But I don't know how to prove it.

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am agree with with-forest about the continuity of the first function. About the second one, it should not be continuous, simply because

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f_2(x)=0$$

whilst

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}f_2(x)=+\infty$$

Answer (score 3):

For the first one, for every $\epsilon > 0$,

if $|x - 0| = |x| < \epsilon$, then $|f_1(x) - f_1(0)| = |f_1(x) - 0| = 
|f_1(x)| = |x| < \epsilon$.

Thus $f_1$ is continuous at $0$.